# installing ros-indigo-libg2o from source

Tags: ros, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've built ros from source. The package i'm using depends on ros-indigo-libg2o as well. Where could I find the source for this?  and how could I build it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227504/installing-ros-indigo-libg2o-from-source/) by [japzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24275/japzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [japzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24275/japzi/) on 2016-02-24**:
I see following location: https://github.com/ros-gbp/libg2o-release but I don't see any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/libg2o) links to https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o

The link you write is release repository link. Though you can see the code using branches, like; https://github.com/ros-gbp/libg2o-release/tree/debian/indigo/libg2o

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3